# Run time error in PHP Static Properties and Accessing Global Instance within a Class

Tags: php, reference, static, static-methods, self

I designed a PHP `Class` with a `Static` Properties and I get a blank page without any `error log`, Kindly assist me whats wrong in my PHP Code?

```
<?php

ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(-1);

class Response
{
    public $Status;
    public $Message;

    function __construct() {
        $this->Status = FALSE;
        $this->Message = "";
    }        
}

$response = new Response();

class Connection
{
    static private $server = "localhost"
    static private $database = "Student";
    static private $user = "ram";
    static private $password = "ram12345!";

    static public $link;

    public static function Trigger() {
        try
        {
            if (!isset(self::$link)) {
                self::$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "bbminfoc_bbm", "Princess4BBM.>") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
                if(!self::$link)
                {
                    $response->Status = FALSE;
                    $response->Message = "Database Connection Failed !";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!mysql_select_db(self::$database, self::$link))
                    {
                        $response->Status = FALSE;
                        $response->Message = "Couldn't select database Main !";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $response->Status = FALSE;
            $response->Message = "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        if(!$response->Status)
        {
            unset(self::$link);
        }
    }
}

if(!isset(Connection::link))
{
    Connection::Trigger();
}

$outp = json_encode($response);

if(isset($outp))
{
    echo($outp);
}
else
{
    echo("No Data");
}

?>
```

Kindly assist me in this code, I don't know what I did wrong in the above pasted code because I can't able to see the log information in error_log file.

Comment: Try adding semicolon after `Connection::Trigger();`

Comment: Are you _really_ certain that you do _not_ get an entry in your http servers error log file? If you have such a definite syntax error in your code that would mean that you have switched of error logging which is something you should _never_ do...

Comment: `json_encode($response);` ? Are you trying to json_encode an object ?

Comment: @SahilGulati - just to print the `JSON` version of a `Response Object`.

Comment: you have syntax errors, two obvious ones. If you're not getting back parse errors, then **it didn't happen.** Unless it never gets there and you're not executing this the way it should be, such as on a host and not as `file:///`.

Comment: 1. `static private $server = "localhost"` missing a `;`. 2. `Connection::link` missing a `$` ~> `Connection::$link`. 3. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051756/run-time-error-in-php-static-properties#comment73188157_43051756) 4. don't use `mysql_functions`. 5. `mysql_functions()` don't throw exceptions, your `try `block is useless.

Comment: @Xorifelse and 3. [It never happened...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43051756/run-time-error-in-php-static-properties#comment73188083_43051756)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @Xorifelse - This is not concept based, **the question is purely issue based**. So we can't say this is duplicate. He is telling he can't able to view the `error_log`, then how could he know problem. We people should help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Yolo already mentioned in the comment, there's a semicolon missing in `Connection::Trigger();` and at `static private $server = "localhost"`. As this will cause a parse error the script will fail before executing and you won't see any errors.

To see those errors you will have to find the php.ini configuration file and set
`display_errors = on`. Also you should consider using an IDE with automatic code linting which will show you potential parse errors while typing the code.

As taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21429652/2232127) answer.

The completely fixed code looks like this:

```
<?php

ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(-1);

class Response
{
    public $Status;
    public $Message;

    function __construct() {
        $this->Status = FALSE;
        $this->Message = "";
    }        
}

$response = new Response();

class Connection
{
    static private $server = "localhost";
    static private $database = "Student";
    static private $user = "ram";
    static private $password = "ram12345!";

    static public $link = null;

    public static function Trigger() {
        global $response;

        try
        {
            if (self::$link !== null) {
                self::$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "bbminfoc_bbm", "Princess4BBM.>") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
                if(!self::$link)
                {
                    $response->Status = FALSE;
                    $response->Message = "Database Connection Failed !";
                }
                else
                {
                    if(!mysql_select_db(self::$database, self::$link))
                    {
                        $response->Status = FALSE;
                        $response->Message = "Couldn't select database Main !";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e) {
            $response->Status = FALSE;
            $response->Message = "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
        }

        if(!$response->Status)
        {
            self::$link = null;
        }
    }
}

if(Connection::$link !== null)
{
    Connection::Trigger();
}

$outp = json_encode($response);

if(isset($outp))
{
    echo($outp);
}
else
{
    echo("No Data");
}

?>
```

Comment: some errors don't display even with `display_errors = on` because it displays to the stderr.  Can you run it from the bash shell?

Comment: *"As taken from this answer."*  - They're already using that.

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan updated the answer to include the fixed code

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan you could also use [this](http://phpcodechecker.com/) site to quickly check the syntax of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I got an following errors `Notice: Undefined variable: response in /home1/abc/public_html/conn.php on line 54

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /home1/abc/public_html/conn.php on line 54

Fatal error: Attempt to unset static property Connection::$link in /home1/abc/public_html/conn.php on line 56`

Comment: @B.Balamanigandan The `$response` variable isn't set in the function. If you want to use the global variable you declared earlier you will need to use `global $response;` at the start of your function. Plus you can't unset static variables. Set it to `null` instead. If that helps you, upvote and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `static private $server = "localhost"` you missed the last `;`

Also, i'm getting this error:
`Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in ... on line 61`

So, change `if(!isset(Connection::link))` to `if (Connection::$link !== null)`

That should solve your problem.

**NOTE**
Please do not use `mysql_*` extension. It's deprecated. If you want to continue using `mysql`, change to [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1):

U dont need to unset connection it will automatically be unset.. after class,

u missed semicolon after localhost, u didn't call response inside function trigger...

```
<?php


    ini_set("display_startup_errors", 1);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
    error_reporting(-1);

    class Response
    {
        public $Status;
        public $Message;

        function __construct() {
            $this->Status = FALSE;
            $this->Message = "";
        }        
    }

    $response = new Response();

    class Connection
    {
        static private $server = "localhost";
        static private $database = "listings";
        static private $user = "root";
        static private $password = "";

        static public $link;

        public static function Trigger() {

            global $response;
            try
            {
                if (!isset(self::$link)) {
                    self::$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Couldn't make connection.");
                    if(!self::$link)
                    {
                        $response->Status = FALSE;
                        $response->Message = "Database Connection Failed !";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(!mysql_select_db(self::$database, self::$link))
                        {
                            $response->Status = FALSE;
                            $response->Message = "Couldn't select database Main !";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e) {
                $response->Status = FALSE;
                $response->Message = "Exception: " . $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
    }

    if(!isset(Connection::$link))
    {
        Connection::Trigger();
    }

    $outp = json_encode($response);

    if(isset($outp))
    {
        echo "hello";
        echo($outp);
    }
    else
    {

        echo "hello";
        echo("No Data");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change this to:**

```
if(!isset(Connection::link))
{
    Connection::Trigger();
}
```

**This:**

```
if(!isset(Connection::$link))
{
    Connection::Trigger();
}
```